# Python PIL text → glDrawPixels

Tags: python, opengl, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to draw some text in PIL, convert the pixels into something I can throw into glDrawPixels and display it. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong; I don't think it's the PIL portion since I've done a bit of testing and everything seems to be working correctly with PIL. I'm at a bit of a loss as the code does not display anything but is not throwing me any errors either so I don't know where to work from.

```
import PIL
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from OpenGL.GL import *

class tooltipText(object):

def __init__(self, x, y, text, font, fontsize, colour):
    self._x = x
    self._y = y
    self._text = text
    self._font = font
    self._fontsize = fontsize
    self._colour = colour
    self._pBits = None

def makeText(self):
    font = ImageFont.truetype(self._font,self._fontsize)
    img=Image.new("RGBA", (300,200),(self._colour[0],self._colour[1],self._colour[2],0))

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    draw.text((0, 200-self._fontsize),self._text,self._colour,font=font)
    img_flip = img.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)

    pBits = img_flip.tobytes("raw", "RGBA")
    self._pBits = pBits
    return self._pBits

def displayText(self):
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    glPushMatrix()
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glTranslate(0, 0,0)
    glRasterPos(self._x,self._y)
    glDrawPixels(300, 200, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, self._pBits)
    glEnd()
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    glPopMatrix()
```

Edit: After poking around a bit I found a solution that works:

```
def displayText(self):
    vPort = glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT)
    glPushMatrix()
    glLoadIdentity()
    glTranslate(self._x, self._y,0)
    glRasterPos(0,0,0)
    glOrtho(0, vPort[2], 0, vPort[3], -1, 1)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glDrawPixels(300, 200, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, self._pBits)
    glEnd()
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    glPopMatrix()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and don't use glDrawPixels. It's poorly supported, slow, and cumbersome to use (as you just found out). The problem with glDrawPixels is, that if the position passed to `glRasterPos` lies outside the viewport after transformation, all raster operations are disables, i.e. glDrawPixels will do nothing.

The better solution is to load the image into a texture a draw a textured quad. Apropos textures. glDrawPixels is not a texturing operating so you enabling a (fixed function) texture target has no effect on it.

---

I don't see the code for it, but I presume you create a window with a OpenGL context in some other part of the code (something must instanciate the class after all).